# Running Juypter Notebook remotely

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv, vscode-remote

I have connected to my Rasp Pi using VSCode from Windows so I can run a Juypter Notebook on the Rasp Pi.

However the Rasp Pi has venv installed and when I try to run the notebook I get a message:

`Running cells with /usr/bin/python' requires ipykernel package.`

[image]

I can accept this message but then get a error that I cant install ipykernel in a externally managed enviroment:

[image]

If in terminal I activate the venv and then type `which python` I get `/home/user`/test_project/venv/bin/python` and then I try to use this path to change interpreter:

Select Another kernel - > Python Environment - > Create Python Environment - >

But then the only option is to create a new venv???

How can I run my juypter notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette then select `Select: Python Interpreter` and paste in the venv path from `which python`

Comment: Hi Al Grant, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: I cant accept my own answer until tomorrow - but I will do :-) Can you vote for the question